# Facebook - Custom audience deleting users issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-custom-audience

I could successfully able to push users into custom audience in facebook in this endpoint - https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/audienceid_goes_here/users

Now I need to delete the user from the custom audience. I tried with the same endpoint but am getting `OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Permissions error"`

Have provided all admin permissions under business settings to systems users and granted all access. Still not sure how to make this work. Am I missing anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Below is the code that I tried

Endpoint - https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/audience_id_goes_here/users

Method - DELETE

```
    payload={
  "schema": [
    "EMAIL_SHA256"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "hashed_email_goes_here"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: @04FS - I have edited with the code that i had tried to send to facebook

Comment: Don’t you need to provide the data under the `payload` key?

Comment: @04FS - Yes i am including payload. Edited again. also am encoding and sending.

Answer (score 3):

Incase anyone is facing the same issue, below is some of the workaround I did.
Tried the delete users from audience using facebook explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

This gives clear error of why it failed. In my case it was due to this message `You cannot remove users from this audience because it will result in a low audience size.` but the error from API in my code was still giving me `Permissions error`.

After checking from fb explorer i got the clear error message.
So there is no resolution for this and its a valid error message as mentioned here - https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2093728693993530

> Custom Audiences must maintain a certain minimum size, though the
>   specific number is not actually documented. I believe the required
>   minimum is approximately 100 unique users. If you need to remove so
>   many users that you're going under this limit, I'd recommend deleting
>   the custom audience entirely.

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Full payload returned from FB in this case...

    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Permissions error",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "error_subcode": 1870047,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Audience Size too Low",
        "error_user_msg": "You cannot remove users from this audience because it will result in a low audience size.",
        "fbtrace_id": "A0bBVOuu0XJbUJH9iPdZADm"
      }
    }

Comment: Wow was banging my head against the desk trying to figure this one out. You saved me a lot of time. Thank you!!